# Ruby helper throws zero division error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, yaml, helper

I am looping through a data file (yaml) in rails like so:

```
<% data.quotations.each_with_index do |quotation,index| %>
   <p class= "quote-<%= quotation_letter_for_index(index) %>">
     <%= quotation.quote %>
   </p>
<% end %>
```

The data loads just fine, but the class generated by `<%= quotation_letter_for_index(index) %>` fails due to a divide by zero error. The ruby helper that powers this is:

```
module QuotationHelpers
  QUOTATION_LETTERS = %w(a b c d e f g h)

  def quotation_letter_for_index(index)
    letter_index = QUOTATION_LETTERS.length % index
    QUOTATION_LETTERS[letter_index]
  end
end
```

The idea is that it would apply letters a-h and repeat.

On load, an error is thrown: `ZeroDivisionError at /
divided by 0`

Any idea what is causing this error? Is this due to the initial index value being 0?

Comment: How are you loading the QuotationHelpers?

Comment: Im using middleman which automatically loads helpers if placed in the helpers directory. I have a number of other helpers that work just fine in the same location. See last line here:  https://middlemanapp.com/basics/helper_methods/

Comment: @FabKremer I used the wrong helper name. Now it loads just fine but it throws a zerodivisionerror. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it seems index zero for first time just add this line at top of the helper method
return QUOTATION_LETTERS[index] if index == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

`letter_index = index % QUOTATION_LETTERS.length`

instead of

`letter_index = QUOTATION_LETTERS.length % index`

The error appears when trying to do `QUOTATION_LETTERS.length % 0`.

Comment: that was it. Thanks much!